# Movie player for "apcs" format .mov video in Linux?

Tags: video, vlc, quicktime

I have a number of video clips that came with the .mov extension.
The video clips open fine in Apple's Quicktime 7 and Quicktime X movie player. However, when I tried to open the files with VLC, I get the following error:

> No suitable decoder module: VLC does
>   not support the audio or video format
>   "apcs". Unfortunately there is no way
>   for you to fix this

The VLC log says (among lots of other output):

> main error: no suitable
>   decoder module for fourcc `apcs'. VLC
>   probably does not support this sound
>   or video format.

For numerous reasons using only Quicktime is not a viable option for me. Is there an alternative player that can play this format?

Answer (score 2):

The correct format full name is `Apple ProRes 422 LT: 'apcs' ('scpa' in little-endian)`.

Link about [Apple ProRes](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Apple_ProRes)

Responding at your question, I quote:

> When it was released you could not open video encoded with ProRes in
>   video players that did not support the Apple QuickTime playback
>   architecture since ProRes was a proprietary Apple encoding format. But
>   in late 2011 an open source decoder became available for ffmpeg as a
>   compile in option.

This is picked by kenjikato from the other StackExchange site that could respond at your question.

[How to play Apple ProRes 422 outside of QuickTime?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6753/how-to-play-apple-prores-422-outside-of-quicktime)

Edit: [VLC has ProRes 422 support since Version 2.0](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.0.0.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try `mplayer`, it's the other major multi-format player on the Linux platform.

I don't know about the *acps* codec, but I've yet to run across something that at least one of mplayer of vlc wouldn't play.